# lilypond:: tacet

Tags: lilypond

In German music-notation, we know the term "tacet" in order to say the musician not to play his chords for a while. How can that be typeset with lilypond? It's similar to "N.C.", but in most common books the text "tacet" is printed.

Comment: "Tacet' is used internationally.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on *how* you want the tacet to be printed. A simple

```
R1*20 ^ \markup{Tacet}
```

will print the word 'Tacet' above the staff:

[image]

Combine it with `\compressFullBarRests` for a short version:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I've tried:

the definition
CMString  = { <c e g>-\markup { \whiteout { \hspace #-2 "Tacet" } } }
CMStringX = #(append (sequential-music-to-chord-exceptions CMString #t)
           ignatzekExceptions)

and use:

   \set   chordNameExceptions = #CMStringX c
   \unset chordNameExceptions

but my "a" is always overlined. Any idea?

Comment: Trying ^ }markup{tacet} in chordmode results in errors

Comment: Ah, I'm using it in regular mode.